Unexpected ANSI escape codes on VS Code integrated terminal
My visual studio code integrated terminal is showing some escaped ANSI codes on every command line:
\x1b7\x1b[38\x3b2\x3b122\x3b122\x3b122m ❮ \x1b[0m\x1b[38\x3b2\x3b159\x3b211\x3b86m


Those are the current settings related to the terminal:
"terminal.integrated.fontSize": 12,
"terminal.integrated.cursorStyle": "line",
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
"terminal.integrated.enableImages": true,
"terminal.integrated.persistentSessionReviveProcess": "never"

I also have Oh My Posh 19.24.2 configured through PowerShell user profile:
oh-my-posh init pwsh --config "C:\Users\sergi\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\themes\slimfat.omp.json" | Invoke-Expression

How to fix?

Appears to be https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/211922 which is fixed in vs code but is as of now still marked as unreleased.

As BDENsys said in their answer, using oh-my-posh init pwsh | Invoke-Expression works. But it is a temporary solution. The ANSI escape overflows still occur in a new instance of VSCode
Adding oh-my-posh init pwsh | Invoke-Expression on $PROFILE wasn't working for me. I resolved it by going to my VS Code settings terminal.integrated.profiles.windows and updating PowerShell settings like this.
"PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell",
            "args": [
                "-NoExit",
                "-Command",
                "oh-my-posh init pwsh | Invoke-Expression"
            ]
        }

Apparently the "args" allows you to run a command whenever Pwsh instance is created.

Hi, thanks for the answer but not sure where is Powershell settings, is it in C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\powershell.config.json ?

@MisterQ it is about VSCode integrated terminal. So open settings and search this: "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows" and choose Edit in settings.json. Copy above code in the proper section, save it and restart the terminal. Thats it.

You need to disable shell integrations in vscode. If you want to enable shell integrations, you can do from your oh-my-posh config using "shell_integration": true.

Checked the schema, I added:
"shell_integration": true
at the root level outside of the blocks array (think I understood correctly?). Just mentioning if it saves someone some time.

check, that's correct.

I had the same issue but, disabling shell integration doesn't help.
If I relaunch command
oh-my-posh init pwsh | Invoke-Expression

the ANSI codes disappear.

I also have the same problem with the exact same ANSI escape code
I found a working Solution which is the following:
-replace the contents of "C:\Users<Your_Username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\contrib\terminal\browser\media\shellIntegration.ps1"
with the contents of this file:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1e790d77f81672c49be070e04474901747115651/src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/browser/media/shellIntegration.ps1
thanks to Kevazy over on the VSCode GitHub!

The problem has been fixed in version 1.90.2, and everything is working correctly now!
There's no need to disable shellIntegration or rerun oh-my-posh init anymore.

Did not help for me, several other people in the thread also has the issue after the fix - so it does not seem as simple as that. (I am on 1.91.1)

I'm on 1.96.0-insider and still have this problem.  It seems to come and go randomly as well.  Driving me nuts.
