Show codes on VS Code (ver 1.90.0) integrated terminal
Windows powershell in my vscode appears this line of code when opened:
\x1b7\x1b[38\x3b2\x3b89\x3b201\x3b165m \x1b[0m\x1b[38\x3b2\x3b224\x3b222\x3b244min \x1b[38\x3b2\x3b75\x3b149\x3b233m\x1b[1mpwsh\x1b[22m\x1b[27m\x1b[38\x3b2\x3b224\x3b222\x3b244m \x1b[0m\x1b[38\x3b2\x3b224\x3b222\x3b244mat \x1b[38\x3b2\x3b75\x3b149\x3b233m\x1b[1m11:41:12\x1b[22m\x1b[0m\x1b8


If I relaunch command

oh-my-posh init pwsh | Invoke-Expression

the ANSI codes disappear.

How to fix?
Other solutions?

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you

I have the same problem, it seemed to happen after VS code updated to the latest version - it used to work fine before I updated.

any relation to https://stackoverflow.com/q/78468557/11107541 ?

I also have the same problem with the exact same ANSI escape code I found a working Solution which is the following: -replace the contents of "C:\Users<Your_Username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\contrib\terminal\browser\media\shellIntegration.ps1"
with the contents of this file:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1e790d77f81672c49be070e04474901747115651/src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/browser/media/shellIntegration.ps1
thanks to Kevazy over on the VSCode GitHub!
(Copied this from my answer to another question on here, seems to be a current problem a lot of ppl are having)

If you install vscode as admin, the file will be in:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\contrib\terminal\browser\media\shellIntegration.ps1

And needs to edit with administrative permissions
